# Play audio at specific times even when the app is in background (IOS13+)

Tags: ios

I have an app which works in the background and has to play specific audio messages at specific times. E.g. an audio message as to be played 1 min after start, Then play another one after 4 min, and then another one after 30 mins. The delay tolerance is only 2 seconds. The problem that the app gets suspended after being a few minutes in the background, and after that time no new audios can be scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

```
func executeAfterDelay(delay: TimeInterval, completion: @escaping(()->Void)){
    backgroundTaskId = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(
        withName: "BackgroundSound",
        expirationHandler: {[weak self] in
            if let taskId = self?.backgroundTaskId{
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(taskId)
            }
        })
    
    let startTime = Date()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        while Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime) < delay{
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.01)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in
            completion()
            if let taskId = self?.backgroundTaskId{
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(taskId)
            }
        }
    }
}
```